# Shutting down rmi server cleanly

Tags: java, rmi

I am running in to some trouble when shutting down the server component and was hoping to get some help.

My server code looks as follows, it has a method to shut down the server

**Server**

```
    private final String address = "127.0.0.1";
    private Registry registry;
    private int port = 6789;

    public RmiServer() throws RemoteException {
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            registry.rebind("rmiServer", this);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to start the server. Exiting the application.", e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }


    public void shutDownServer() throws RemoteException {
        int succesful = 0;
        try {
            registry.unbind("rmiServer");
            UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this, true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            logger.error("Error shutting down the server - could not unbind the registry", e);
            succesful = -1;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.info("Unable to sleep when shutting down the server", e);
            succesful = -1;
        }
        catch (AccessException e) {
            logger.info("Access Exception", e);
            succesful = -1;
        }
        catch (UnmarshalException e) {
            System.out.println(e.detail.getMessage());
            logger.info("UnMarshall Exception", e);
            succesful = -1;
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println(e.detail.getMessage());
            logger.info("Remote Exception", e);
            succesful = -1;
        }

        logger.info("server shut down gracefully");     
        System.exit(succesful);
}
```

My client connects fine, no issues, so to shutdown i created a new application, copied the client code to connect and then call the close method on the server

**Shutdown**

public class Shutdown {

```
private String serverAddress = "127.0.0.1";
private String serverPort = "6789";
private ReceiveMessageInterface rmiServer;
private Registry registry;

public Shutdown(){
    try {
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverAddress, (new Integer(serverPort)).intValue());
        rmiServer = (ReceiveMessageInterface) (registry.lookup("rmiServer"));
        logger.info("Client started correctly");
        rmiServer.shutDownServer();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (UnmarshalException e ){
        logger.error("Unmarshall exception. Exiting application", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        logger.error("Remote object exception occured when connecting to server. Exiting application", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        logger.error("Not Bound Exception occured when connecting to server. Exiting application", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

No matter what i try i keep getting the following exception;

```
ERROR com.rmi.client.RMIClient - Unmarshall exception. Exiting application
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at $Proxy0.shutDownServer(Unknown Source)
    at com.rmi.shutdown.Shutdown.<init>(Shutdown.java:31)
    at com.rmi.shutdown.Shutdown.main(Shutdown.java:52)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I belive this might be due to the fact that the client is not properly disconnected and just gets "cut off" but i am unsure how else to disconnect the server side?

please can some one advise.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Unexport with force = true doesn't abort calls in progress. In general it will let in-progress calls run to completion. Your `shutDownServer` method is almost correct in that it unregisters the remote reference and unexports it. What it does next doesn't work, though. First, it sleeps for one second. This keeps the call in progress and keeps the client waiting for a reply. Then the shutdown code exits the server JVM without returning from the remote call. This closes client's connection while it's still awaiting a reply. That's why the client gets the connection reset exception.

To shut down cleanly, unregister the remote object, unexport it with force = true (as you've done) and then simply return. This will send a reply to the client, letting its remote call complete, and it will then exit. Back on the server, after the last in-progress call has completed, if there are no other objects exported, and if there's nothing else keeping the JVM around (such as non-daemon threads) the JVM will exit. You need to let RMI finish up its server-side processing instead of calling `System.exit()`.

Comment: Could you explain the following:"and then simply return"? What return?

Comment: @iJava Returning from the method normally, as opposed to throwing an exception or calling `System.exit()`. In this case removing all the exit() calls will let control run off the end of the method, which will work. A `return` statement would also work.

Comment: The correct order of the method invocation is: `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this, true);` then
`registry.unbind("rmiServer");` Its works when the bind has been failed during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The system is doing exactly what you told it to do. You told it to unexport itself, and you set the 'force' parameter to true, which aborts calls in progress, so it unexported itself and aborted the call in progress. Just ignore it, or if you insist on a clean response to the shutdown client, have the server start a new thread for the unexport operation, with a short delay so the shutdown call can return to the client.

Comment: @ejb i want also to close the client ,like a database connection .close any help ?

Comment: `force` being `true` does _not_ abort calls in progress, it only prevents new calls from being made. Existing calls will run to completion.